# Best way to loop through values and pass each value to query in SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `select` query which returns a list of table names. I want to pass each table name to a `drop table` query so that I can drop the table. I can use temp tables. Is this the best way to do this? Is there any other way?

Comment: How many tables are you talking about?

Comment: For now, I have 300 to 400 tables, in future it may increase..

Answer (score 0):

A bit dangerous make sure you specify the database with USE...
Or substitute the select from SYS.tables with your query to return the table names.

```
USE [ENTERDATEBASENAME]
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_DROP') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP_DROP;   
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_DROP FROM SYS.tables

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #TEMP_DROP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TABLEBNAME VARCHAR(MAX),@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @TABLEBNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 [NAME] FROM #TEMP_DROP)
    SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' +  @TABLEBNAME
    EXEC(@SQL)
    DELETE FROM #TEMP_DROP where [name] = @TABLEBNAME
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a loop for this. It is a lot more code to write to use a cursor here than some simple dynamic sql, and you need to use dynamic sql for this anyway. But keep in mind that dropping a bunch of tables can be problematic if you have foreign keys. You either need to remove those foreign keys or drop the tables in a specific order.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'drop table ' + quotename(TableName) + ';'
from YourQueryThatGivesYouTableNames

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```